# align nodes at glyphs

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

I have a `pgfplots` graphic that looks like this:

[image]

The code, which I procedurally generate with a python script, looks like this:

```
\documentclass[margin=1pt,]{standalone}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\ifpdftex\usepackage[scaled=1]{helvet}\fi
\ifxetex\usepackage{fontspec}\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}\fi
\usepackage[helvet]{sfmath}
\usepackage{amsmath,latexsym}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,positioning,patterns}
\tikzset{cross/.style={cross out, draw=black, minimum size=2*(#1-\pgflinewidth), inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},cross/.default={3pt}}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{scaled x ticks=false}
\definecolor{myyellow}{rgb}{0.96,0.742,0.29}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.1,0.32,0.738}
\definecolor{myotheryellow}{rgb}{0.98828125,0.5625,0.13671875}
\definecolor{myotherblue}{rgb}{0.18359375,0.3515625,0.7578125}
\providecommand\ATLASlabel{Internal}
\renewcommand\sfdefault{phv}
\renewcommand\rmdefault{phv}
\renewcommand\ttdefault{pcr}
\font\greekcapstenrm=cmr10
\font\greekcapssevenrm=cmr7
\font\greekcapsfiverm=cmr5
\newfam\greekcapsfam
\textfont\greekcapsfam=\greekcapstenrm
\scriptfont\greekcapsfam=\greekcapssevenrm
\scriptscriptfont\greekcapsfam=\greekcapsfiverm
\let\tmpLambda=\Lambda \def\Lambda{{\fam\greekcapsfam\tmpLambda}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width = 0.8\textwidth,
    width = 0.8\textwidth,
    y=1cm,
    xlabel = {\textsf{Parameter Value}}, 
    clip = false,
    ymin=-0.5,
    ymax= 13.5,
    xmin=0.5218352188569495,
    xmax=1.6920683616453638,
    minor tick num=4,
    ytick style={draw=none},
    yticklabels=\empty,
    enlarge x limits=true,
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    scaled ticks=false,
]
\node at ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,0}) [anchor = east]{\textsf{norm\_bkg}};
\node at ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,1}) [anchor = east]{\textsf{mu}};
\node at ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,2}) [anchor = east]{\textsf{gamma\_stat\_SR\_bin\_9}};
\node at ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,3}) [anchor = east]{\textsf{gamma\_stat\_SR\_bin\_8}};
\node at ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,4}) [anchor = east]{\textsf{gamma\_stat\_SR\_bin\_7}};
\node at ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,5}) [anchor = east]{\textsf{gamma\_stat\_SR\_bin\_6}};
\node at ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,6}) [anchor = east]{\textsf{gamma\_stat\_SR\_bin\_5}};
\node at ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,7}) [anchor = east]{\textsf{gamma\_stat\_SR\_bin\_4}};
\node at ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,8}) [anchor = east]{\textsf{gamma\_stat\_SR\_bin\_3}};
\node at ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,9}) [anchor = east]{\textsf{gamma\_stat\_SR\_bin\_2}};
\node at ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,10}) [anchor = east]{\textsf{gamma\_stat\_SR\_bin\_10}};
\node at ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,11}) [anchor = east]{\textsf{gamma\_stat\_SR\_bin\_1}};
\node at ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,12}) [anchor = east]{\textsf{gamma\_stat\_SR\_bin\_0}};
\node at ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,13}) [anchor = east]{\textsf{gamma\_stat\_CR\_bin\_0}};
  \draw[color=red,solid] (axis cs:0.96608,0.00)--(axis cs:1.02975,0.00);
  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,color=red,draw=none] at (axis cs:0.99791,0.00){};
  \node[xshift=3em,anchor=base] at ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,0.0}) {$0.998^{+0.032}_{-0.032}$};
  \draw[color=red,solid] (axis cs:0.52184,1.00)--(axis cs:1.69207,1.00);
  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,color=red,draw=none] at (axis cs:1.10187,1.00){};
  \node[xshift=3em,anchor=base] at ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,1.0}) {$1.1^{+0.6}_{-0.6}$};
  \draw[color=red,solid] (axis cs:0.95813,2.00)--(axis cs:1.04271,2.00);
  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,color=red,draw=none] at (axis cs:1.00042,2.00){};
  \node[xshift=3em,anchor=base] at ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,2.0}) {$1.00^{+0.04}_{-0.04}$};
  \draw[color=red,solid] (axis cs:0.95197,3.00)--(axis cs:1.03637,3.00);
  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,color=red,draw=none] at (axis cs:0.99417,3.00){};
  \node[xshift=3em,anchor=base] at ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,3.0}) {$0.99^{+0.04}_{-0.04}$};
  \draw[color=red,solid] (axis cs:0.96731,4.00)--(axis cs:1.04759,4.00);
  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,color=red,draw=none] at (axis cs:1.00745,4.00){};
  \node[xshift=3em,anchor=base] at ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,4.0}) {$1.01^{+0.04}_{-0.04}$};
  \draw[color=red,solid] (axis cs:0.97100,5.00)--(axis cs:1.05142,5.00);
  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,color=red,draw=none] at (axis cs:1.01121,5.00){};
  \node[xshift=3em,anchor=base] at ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,5.0}) {$1.01^{+0.04}_{-0.04}$};
  \draw[color=red,solid] (axis cs:0.95597,6.00)--(axis cs:1.03721,6.00);
  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,color=red,draw=none] at (axis cs:0.99659,6.00){};
  \node[xshift=3em,anchor=base] at ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,6.0}) {$1.00^{+0.04}_{-0.04}$};
  \draw[color=red,solid] (axis cs:0.96513,7.00)--(axis cs:1.04544,7.00);
  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,color=red,draw=none] at (axis cs:1.00528,7.00){};
  \node[xshift=3em,anchor=base] at ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,7.0}) {$1.01^{+0.04}_{-0.04}$};
  \draw[color=red,solid] (axis cs:0.96977,8.00)--(axis cs:1.05069,8.00);
  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,color=red,draw=none] at (axis cs:1.01023,8.00){};
  \node[xshift=3em,anchor=base] at ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,8.0}) {$1.01^{+0.04}_{-0.04}$};
  \draw[color=red,solid] (axis cs:0.93833,9.00)--(axis cs:1.02097,9.00);
  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,color=red,draw=none] at (axis cs:0.97965,9.00){};
  \node[xshift=3em,anchor=base] at ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,9.0}) {$0.98^{+0.04}_{-0.04}$};
  \draw[color=red,solid] (axis cs:0.96196,10.00)--(axis cs:1.04405,10.00);
  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,color=red,draw=none] at (axis cs:1.00301,10.00){};
  \node[xshift=3em,anchor=base] at ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,10.0}) {$1.00^{+0.04}_{-0.04}$};
  \draw[color=red,solid] (axis cs:0.95952,11.00)--(axis cs:1.04276,11.00);
  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,color=red,draw=none] at (axis cs:1.00114,11.00){};
  \node[xshift=3em,anchor=base] at ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,11.0}) {$1.00^{+0.04}_{-0.04}$};
  \draw[color=red,solid] (axis cs:0.94300,12.00)--(axis cs:1.02794,12.00);
  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,color=red,draw=none] at (axis cs:0.98547,12.00){};
  \node[xshift=3em,anchor=base] at ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,12.0}) {$0.99^{+0.04}_{-0.04}$};
  \draw[color=red,solid] (axis cs:0.99900,13.00)--(axis cs:1.00100,13.00);
  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,color=red,draw=none] at (axis cs:1.00000,13.00){};
  \node[xshift=3em,anchor=base] at ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,13.0}) {$1.000^{+0.001}_{-0.001}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm pretty happy with it, except for one detail:
The label nodes on the right hand side are not aligned in any meaningful way - I would like to have them horizontally aligned such that the dots are all on the same (imaginary) vertical line.

I could imagine doing this in several different ways:

- splitting the nodes to have one node with the numbers before the dot, and then the remainder of the node.
- using some `\rlap` magic in the node to avoid the numbers before the dot being counted to the bounding box

But I'm unsure whether there is not a more elegant way to achieve this.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: There should be a solution involving `siunitx` package.

Comment: @SebGlav PGF/Ti*k*Z have a parser. Look at section 92 of the PGFmanual. I've never used it.

Answer (score 1):

> Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Why don't you replace `anchor=base` by `anchor=west`?

[image: pgfplots alignment]

```
\documentclass[margin=1pt,]{standalone}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\ifpdftex\usepackage[scaled=1]{helvet}\fi
\ifxetex\usepackage{fontspec}\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}\fi
\usepackage[helvet]{sfmath}
\usepackage{amsmath,latexsym}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,positioning,patterns}
\tikzset{cross/.style={cross out, draw=black, minimum size=2*(#1-\pgflinewidth), inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},cross/.default={3pt}}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{scaled x ticks=false}
\definecolor{myyellow}{rgb}{0.96,0.742,0.29}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.1,0.32,0.738}
\definecolor{myotheryellow}{rgb}{0.98828125,0.5625,0.13671875}
\definecolor{myotherblue}{rgb}{0.18359375,0.3515625,0.7578125}
\providecommand\ATLASlabel{Internal}
\renewcommand\sfdefault{phv}
\renewcommand\rmdefault{phv}
\renewcommand\ttdefault{pcr}
\font\greekcapstenrm=cmr10
\font\greekcapssevenrm=cmr7
\font\greekcapsfiverm=cmr5
\newfam\greekcapsfam
\textfont\greekcapsfam=\greekcapstenrm
\scriptfont\greekcapsfam=\greekcapssevenrm
\scriptscriptfont\greekcapsfam=\greekcapsfiverm
\let\tmpLambda=\Lambda \def\Lambda{{\fam\greekcapsfam\tmpLambda}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width = 0.8\textwidth,
    width = 0.8\textwidth,
    y=1cm,
    xlabel = {\textsf{Parameter Value}}, 
    clip = false,
    ymin=-0.5,
    ymax= 13.5,
    xmin=0.5218352188569495,
    xmax=1.6920683616453638,
    minor tick num=4,
    ytick style={draw=none},
    yticklabels=\empty,
    enlarge x limits=true,
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    scaled ticks=false
]
\node at ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,0}) [anchor = east]{\textsf{norm\_bkg}};
\node at ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,1}) [anchor = east]{\textsf{mu}};
\node at ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,2}) [anchor = east]{\textsf{gamma\_stat\_SR\_bin\_9}};
\node at ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,3}) [anchor = east]{\textsf{gamma\_stat\_SR\_bin\_8}};
\node at ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,4}) [anchor = east]{\textsf{gamma\_stat\_SR\_bin\_7}};
\node at ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,5}) [anchor = east]{\textsf{gamma\_stat\_SR\_bin\_6}};
\node at ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,6}) [anchor = east]{\textsf{gamma\_stat\_SR\_bin\_5}};
\node at ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,7}) [anchor = east]{\textsf{gamma\_stat\_SR\_bin\_4}};
\node at ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,8}) [anchor = east]{\textsf{gamma\_stat\_SR\_bin\_3}};
\node at ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,9}) [anchor = east]{\textsf{gamma\_stat\_SR\_bin\_2}};
\node at ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,10}) [anchor = east]{\textsf{gamma\_stat\_SR\_bin\_10}};
\node at ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,11}) [anchor = east]{\textsf{gamma\_stat\_SR\_bin\_1}};
\node at ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,12}) [anchor = east]{\textsf{gamma\_stat\_SR\_bin\_0}};
\node at ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,13}) [anchor = east]{\textsf{gamma\_stat\_CR\_bin\_0}};
  \draw[color=red,solid] (axis cs:0.96608,0.00)--(axis cs:1.02975,0.00);
  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,color=red,draw=none] at (axis cs:0.99791,0.00){};
  \node[anchor=west] at ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,0.0}) {$0.998^{+0.032}_{-0.032}$};
  \draw[color=red,solid] (axis cs:0.52184,1.00)--(axis cs:1.69207,1.00);
  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,color=red,draw=none] at (axis cs:1.10187,1.00){};
  \node[anchor=west] at ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,1.0}) {$1.1^{+0.6}_{-0.6}$};
  \draw[color=red,solid] (axis cs:0.95813,2.00)--(axis cs:1.04271,2.00);
  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,color=red,draw=none] at (axis cs:1.00042,2.00){};
  \node[anchor=west] at ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,2.0}) {$1.00^{+0.04}_{-0.04}$};
  \draw[color=red,solid] (axis cs:0.95197,3.00)--(axis cs:1.03637,3.00);
  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,color=red,draw=none] at (axis cs:0.99417,3.00){};
  \node[anchor=west] at ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,3.0}) {$0.99^{+0.04}_{-0.04}$};
  \draw[color=red,solid] (axis cs:0.96731,4.00)--(axis cs:1.04759,4.00);
  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,color=red,draw=none] at (axis cs:1.00745,4.00){};
  \node[anchor=west] at ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,4.0}) {$1.01^{+0.04}_{-0.04}$};
  \draw[color=red,solid] (axis cs:0.97100,5.00)--(axis cs:1.05142,5.00);
  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,color=red,draw=none] at (axis cs:1.01121,5.00){};
  \node[anchor=west] at ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,5.0}) {$1.01^{+0.04}_{-0.04}$};
  \draw[color=red,solid] (axis cs:0.95597,6.00)--(axis cs:1.03721,6.00);
  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,color=red,draw=none] at (axis cs:0.99659,6.00){};
  \node[anchor=west] at ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,6.0}) {$1.00^{+0.04}_{-0.04}$};
  \draw[color=red,solid] (axis cs:0.96513,7.00)--(axis cs:1.04544,7.00);
  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,color=red,draw=none] at (axis cs:1.00528,7.00){};
  \node[anchor=west] at ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,7.0}) {$1.01^{+0.04}_{-0.04}$};
  \draw[color=red,solid] (axis cs:0.96977,8.00)--(axis cs:1.05069,8.00);
  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,color=red,draw=none] at (axis cs:1.01023,8.00){};
  \node[anchor=west] at ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,8.0}) {$1.01^{+0.04}_{-0.04}$};
  \draw[color=red,solid] (axis cs:0.93833,9.00)--(axis cs:1.02097,9.00);
  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,color=red,draw=none] at (axis cs:0.97965,9.00){};
  \node[anchor=west] at ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,9.0}) {$0.98^{+0.04}_{-0.04}$};
  \draw[color=red,solid] (axis cs:0.96196,10.00)--(axis cs:1.04405,10.00);
  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,color=red,draw=none] at (axis cs:1.00301,10.00){};
  \node[anchor=west] at ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,10.0}) {$1.00^{+0.04}_{-0.04}$};
  \draw[color=red,solid] (axis cs:0.95952,11.00)--(axis cs:1.04276,11.00);
  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,color=red,draw=none] at (axis cs:1.00114,11.00){};
  \node[anchor=west] at ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,11.0}) {$1.00^{+0.04}_{-0.04}$};
  \draw[color=red,solid] (axis cs:0.94300,12.00)--(axis cs:1.02794,12.00);
  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,color=red,draw=none] at (axis cs:0.98547,12.00){};
  \node[anchor=west] at ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,12.0}) {$0.99^{+0.04}_{-0.04}$};
  \draw[color=red,solid] (axis cs:0.99900,13.00)--(axis cs:1.00100,13.00);
  \node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt,color=red,draw=none] at (axis cs:1.00000,13.00){};
  \node[anchor=west] at ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,13.0}) {$1.000^{+0.001}_{-0.001}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's very nice, but only works if the numbers have the same number of digits before the dot. As I procedurally generate this code, I would like a solution that is agnostic of the value of the number put there.

Comment: You're right. There's some questions about that, that were answered before, but it involves a bit ow plain TeX work, I think.

Comment: This syntax here works, but is not very elegant:

`  \node[xshift=1em,anchor=base west] at ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,3.0}) {\ensuremath{\llap{\ensuremath{0}}.99^{+0.04}_{-0.04}}};`